# how to create web component on angular and use in another app

Tags: angular, package, web-component

I'm trying to create a web component on an angular app, but I don't know  how to use that web component on another app (micro front end concept), please I need to explain step by step

Comment: Why not write a native, vanilla, no framework Web Component and use it everywhere. That is *why* they were created.

Answer (score 0):

You can create libraries and use it in your apps.
Check this example by Nrwl-nx
https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to google a bit about NX and monorepos concept. It is a system, which is basically one big repository with alot of functionality, in which you share files between apps, libraries etc. So you would have angular library (contains your component), which you would use in multiple apps. You would have to do a few adjustments to move from just Angular CLI project to NX.